# avghookx.dll Cannot find or open the PDB file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I tried to debug my program and got:

> 'SuperHeros.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\yossi\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2013\Projects\SuperHeros\Debug\SuperHeros.exe'. Symbols loaded.
>   'SuperHeros.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'SuperHeros.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'SuperHeros.exe'
>   (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
>   'SuperHeros.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp120d.dll'.
>   Symbols loaded. 'SuperHeros.exe' (Win32): Loaded
>   'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr120d.dll'. Symbols loaded. 'SuperHeros.exe'
>   (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\AVG\AVG2015\avghookx.dll'.
>   Cannot find or open the PDB file. The program '[5472] SuperHeros.exe'
>   has exited with code 0 (0x0).

Why is Visual Basic trying to load an AVG AntiVirus file? How can I prevent this loading?

I'm using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: This isn't really a programming question, so is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Anti-malware injects itself into every program.  Just like a virus.  The only way to prevent this is by uninstalling the virus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Try this:

> I disable AVG ,It worked without notify .

Answer (score 0):

By adding an exception in AVG for the program which launches the eventual error, you can also avoid the error. For example, iisexpress.exe was getting a BEX error (memory out of range) due to avghookx.dll_unloaded. By creating an exception for iisexpress.exe, that BEX error stopped happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your Antivirus initially checks Whether the file contains any malicious content or not, before deploying your application and it will takes 15 seconds of time to complete action.If you want to  wait 15 seconds you can wait else you simply disable your antivirus temporary.

Comment: Please add any reference of "15 seconds of time to complete action". Also is 15 second time only applicable for AVG?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling [Behaviour Shield](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60rE3.png) in Avast worked for me.
That is, I no longer see this:
'C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\aswhookx.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.